# How to use an angular filter to search an array of objects with results limited bv more than one property

Tags: angularjs, object, filter, properties

I am attempting to apply the standard angular filter to an array of objects but I am not wanting to have the search text be applied to the entire object, rather only certain properties. For example, if I have an array of objects that looks like

```
$scope.ppl = 
    [{
      "name": "Sue",
      "age": 37,
      "location": "40.5630° N, 122.3255° W"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ann",
      "age": 40,
      "location": "37.7749° N, 122.4194° W"
    }]
```

and I'd like to find anyone age 37, if my search text is "37", I get back both items in the array because 37 matches both the age on Sue and a portion of the location on Ann, though I had no interest in this latter property.

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), I do see that it's possible to limit the property of interest in an array of objects with object notation. It works just fine for me to use as a filter expression in my html

```
ng-repeat="person in ppl | filter:{age: searchText}"
```

with an input set to `ng-model="searchText"`

Perfectly fine. However I want to search on more than just one property, while still not including ALL of them.

I thought it would be something like

`ng-repeat="person in ppl | filter:{age: searchText, name: searchText}"` <-- **note the added property**

however upon more closely reading the documentation, i found that this limits the results to an object having *both* properties match the model, as opposed to *either*.

Does anyone know of a way of filtering such that the results include a match on property X || property Y as opposed to property X && property Y?

Thanks!

Comment: use a custom filter

Comment: @charlietfl, Sure. I'll definitely do that if there's no clever/baked in way of doing it without. I tend to do stuff like that (write your own!) as a first resort only to find someone's already come up with a cleaner or simpler way, so i'm just wanting to confirm first that one such doesn't exist already. thx. :)

Comment: don't think there is for an "or" condition